# Checkboxes not showing for Drupal form

Tags: php, drupal

I am trying to get a Drupal form to show checkboxes, but I seem to be having no luck.

```
function multi_reg_pagecreate() {
    $multi_reg_checkbox = multi_reg_checkbox();

    print_r($multi_reg_checkbox);

    $form['multi_reg_checkbox'] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkboxes',
        '#options' => $multi_reg_checkbox,
        '#description' => t('Register for multiple events here')
        );

    return $form;
}
```

The data is in this format:

```
Array ( [22] => Test Event Reg [23] => Test Event Reg 2 )
```

Which seems similar to what is said in the example:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/6#checkbox

What am I not doing right?

EDIT:

I'm seeing this on the page displayed:

```
<form id="multi-reg-pagecreate" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" action="/domain/multiple-registration">
<div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkboxes form-item-multi-reg-checkbox">
<label for="edit-multi-reg-checkbox">Events </label>
<div id="edit-multi-reg-checkbox" class="form-checkboxes"></div>
<div class="description">Register for multiple events here</div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" value="form-t_KSPV9ULp71yMEUHCtDUKV4R3M18M4ie2_M6cj-ZVU" name="form_build_id">
<input type="hidden" value="RzzEFjyCz29CjH9F9PAB5UV9Xq9VBCx8mTY_HppLfiA" name="form_token">
<input type="hidden" value="multi_reg_pagecreate" name="form_id">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: your fapi(form API) appears to be correct.are u rendering the form using drupal_render(drupal_get_form('multi_reg_pagecreate')).or IF U r using a custom theme then u should write a theme for ur check box

Comment: What do you see when the form is rendered? Do you get any warning messages?

Comment: No warning messages or notices, no, not even after turning them on.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the way my data is organized. I put in some dummy data using the method that is used on Drupal.org and it works fine. So I need to drill down what's wrong with my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function multi_reg_pagecreate($form, &$form_state) {
    $multi_reg_checkbox = multi_reg_checkbox();
    $form['multi_reg_checkbox'] = array(
        '#title'       => t('Events'),
        '#type'        => 'checkboxes',
        '#options'     => $multi_reg_checkbox,
        '#description' => t('Register for multiple events here')
    );
    return $form;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Options has to look like:

```
'#options' => array (
    0 => t('Monday'),
    1 => t('Tuesday'),
    2 => t('Wednesday'),
    3 => t('Thursday'),
    4 => t('Friday'),
    5 => t('Saturday'),
    6 => t('Sunday'),
),
```

or:

```
'#options' => drupal_map_assoc(
    array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
),
```

... looks like:

[image]

Please post your screen from your current devel output of **$multi_reg_checkbox**

Comment: The event title is displaying, as well as the description, but the actual checkboxes are not displaying.

Comment: Please post your screen from your current devel output of **$multi_reg_checkbox**

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old... but... how are you calling the form? Are you doing it from a hook_menu? If so: did you make sure to put

'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
'page arguments' => array('multi_reg_pagecreate'),